using group_concat gives error while grouping columns
Given table called events with columns dt (timestamp) and type (event type, example buy, sell, other)
I want to get all the events that happened in 2021 in Quarter wise.
The result should hold 2 columns:

column1 = Quarter number followed by single quote and then last 2 digits of year.
example Q1'21, Q2'21, Q3'21, Q4'21

column2 = Format is ##=##, first ## indicates the type of event, and next # indicates total number of events of this particular type.

Separate the types by semicolon and space.
Sort this by descending order by total number of events and then the ascending order of type.


Sort the results in ascending order of column1.


I am able to write query to get individual columns, but when I combine them together I am getting errors with group columns.
Here is my query:

To get column1:

select concat('Q', Quarter(dt), "'", RIGHT(YEAR(dt), 2)) as c1 
from events


To get column2:

select group_concat(concat(type, '=', cnt)) as c2 
from (
    select type, count(*) as cnt, quarter(dt) as qtr
    from events where year(dt) = 2021 
    group by type, qtr

What is the correct way to solve this?
sample input:
2021-02-10 12:10:32    sell
2021-01-10 01:10:32    buy
2021-03-10 13:10:32    other
2021-11-10 13:10:32    buy
2021-12-10 13:10:32    sell

sample output:
Q1'21    buy=1; other=1; sell=1
Q4'21    buy=1; sell=1


Please add sample input and the desired result.

Include the year in the subquery's grouping.
SELECT CONCAT(q, "'", y) AS c1, GROUP_CONCAT(type, '=', cnt ORDER BY cnt DESC, type) AS c2
FROM (
    SELECT type, QUARTER(dt) AS q, RIGHT(YEAR(dt), 2) AS y, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM events
    GROUP BY type, y, q
)
GROUP BY c1

Note that it's not necessary to use CONCAT() inside GROUP_CONCAT(), it automatically concatenates all the arguments.

Thank you, what is the use of  % 100 in this query?

It's the modulus operator, it gets the remainder when dividing by 100, so it gets the last 2 digits of the year.

But I just realized that it's wrong, because this won't do the right thing for years 2001-2009.

Data
CREATE TABLE YOURTABLE(
   date   DATETIME   NOT NULL 
  ,opinon VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO YOURTABLE
(date,opinon) VALUES 
('2021-02-10 12:10:32','sell'),
('2021-01-10 01:10:32','buy'),
('2021-03-10 13:10:32','other'),
('2021-11-10 13:10:32','buy'),
('2021-12-10 13:10:32','sell');

use subquery, concat, Group_concat and right as follows
SELECT date1,
       Group_concat(opinon ORDER BY date1 SEPARATOR ';') OPINION
FROM   (SELECT Concat('Q', Quarter(date), '''', RIGHT(Year(date), 2)) DATE1,
               Concat(opinon, '=1')                                   opinon
        FROM   yourtable) A
GROUP  BY date1  

dbfiddle
